# Should we use drupal_exit() after drupal_goto()?

Tags: 7

I think, [drupal_goto()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x) breaks the execution so next lines of code won't execute after `drupal_goto()`, Am I right? Somebody recommended me to use [drupal_exit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7.x) on the next line of the `drupal_goto()`.

Is it necessary? Will the code after `drupal_goto()` execute ?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the code after drupal_goto() execute ?

No - the last line of `drupal_goto()` is:

```
drupal_exit($url);
```

So the script will already have terminated without returning, and no subsequent code will execute.

You can safely ignore that recommendation.

Comment: Yes, just noted that. I think, it has been added in recent updates of drupal.

Comment: Not exactly, it's been there since the very beginning (v7.0)